# Amend d3 graph to include all points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In below code the axes the outer points are being truncated :

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
    body {
        font: 11px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {


        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var xValue = function (d) {
            return d.x;
        }

        xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]) // value -> display
        xMap = function (d) {
            return xScale(xValue(d));
        }
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");


        var yValue = function (d) {
            return d["y"];
        } // data -> value
        yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]) // value -> display
        yMap = function (d) {
            return yScale(yValue(d));
        } // data -> display
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");

        var rValue = function (d) {
            return d["r"];
        } // data -> value
        rMap = function (d) {
            return d["r"];
        } // data -> display

        // setup fill color
        var cValue = function (d) {
                    return d.Manufacturer;
                },
                color = d3.scale.category10();

        // add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // add the tooltip area to the webpage
        var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0);

        /*   d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {*/

        var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("pre#data").text());

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.x = +d.x;
            d["y"] = +d["y"];
        });

        // don't want dots overlapping axis, so add in buffer to data domain
        xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue) - 1, d3.max(data, xValue) + 1]);
        yScale.domain([d3.min(data, yValue) - 1, d3.max(data, yValue) + 1]);

        // x-axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("x", width)
                .attr("y", -6)
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("x value");

        // y-axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("y value");

        // draw dots
        svg.selectAll(".dot")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("stroke", "red")
                .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
                .attr("r", rMap)
                .attr("cx", xMap)
                .attr("cy", yMap)
                .style("fill", "none")
        // });
    });

</script>

<pre style="display:none" id="data">
label,x,y,r
l1,100,30,50
l2,5,5,100
l3,50,50,20

</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/zzz8svuq/6/

How can I amend axes so that circle points appear entirely within the graph ?

I've tried amending the width of the graph but this just updates the x axis points :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjust your margins, so

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 130, left: 140}
```

You'll also have to make some other adjustments such as your xScale range (just subtract the left and right margins to make sure the scale stays within view).

```
xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right])
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vfmd51ew/)